# Join Operation for Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Step 1.    i/p= “wwwwaaadexxxxxx”

Step 2.    converted= {'w': 4, 'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'x': 6}

Step Final.    o/p= 'w4a3d1e1x6'

I'm on S2 how to go to final step ?

Would appreciated direct conversions 1-> Final

Time Complexity should be less but would appreciate any Sol.

I want to return in form of String stored in any var

without importing anything

Comment: What exactly was the difficulty that led you to asking a question here?

Comment: Show what you tried yourself as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a comprehension(But you need to convert those numbers to string), Try code below:

```
converted = {'w': 4, 'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'x': 6}
print("".join([str(char) for k, v in converted.items() for char in (k, v)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

ip = "wwwwaaadexxxxxx"
op = "".join(f"{k}{len(list(g))}" for k, g in groupby(ip))
# 'w4a3d1e1x6'
```

Answer (score 0):

use Counter

```
from collections import Counter
ip= "wwwwaaadexxxxxx"

print(''.join([i+str(x) for i, x in Counter(ip).items()]))

#'w4a3d1e1x6'
```

Comment: That would group together different sections of the same letter. Which from the cited Step 2 may be intended, but with this looking like a string compression exercise, I doubt it's actually wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'w': 4, 'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'x': 6}
for k,c in zip(d.keys(),d.values()): 
    print(k+str(c),end='')
```

You can try this, see if it helps