# How to join all keys and values of dictionary and return in form of string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Step 1.    i/p= “wwwwaaadexxxxxx”

Step 2.    converted= {'w': 4, 'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'x': 6}

Step Final.    o/p= 'w4a3d1e1x6'

I'm on S2 how to go to final step ?

Would appreciated direct conversions 1-> Final

Time Complexity should be less but would appreciate any Sol.

I want to return in form of String stored in any var

without importing anything

Comment: Do you happen to have the code that got you all the way to step 2?

Comment: Whats the difference to the question you asked yesterday ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65146588/join-operation-for-dictionary-in-python

Comment: No imports, or std lib imports:  `lambda s:  ''.join(f'{k}{v}' for k, v in {c: s.count(c) for c in set(s)}.items())`.
Where `s` is your string.  Although `set` isn't ordered :(

Answer (score 2):

You can get ket and value pairs (using `dict.items()`) and parse them as a `list`, then use `join` to create a string out of it!

```
converted= {'w': 4, 'a': 3, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'x': 6}
print(''.join([f"{k}{v}" for k,v in converted.items()]))
```

```
w4a3d1e1x6
```

OR use `Counter`

`Counter` is from `collections` module that will give you a `dict` like structure with Count of each character

```
from collections import Counter
my_str = 'wwwwaaadexxxxxx'
print(''.join([f"{k}{v}" for k,v in Counter(my_str).items()]))
```

Comment: @PeteBadger If your query is resolved, please mark this as an answer!